# Autoplay on Background Image Slider

Tags: jquery, css, slider, background-image, autoplay

I am modifying a background image slider for my site. What I have is PERFECT, I just need to make it autoplay.

https://jsfiddle.net/eabarrio1/Ls4onLne/

```
function slideTo(slide) {
$("#slider .active").fadeOut().removeClass("active");
$("#slider .bg-slider").eq(slide).fadeIn().addClass("active");
$(".nav-dots .current").removeClass("current");
$(".nav-dots div").eq(slide).addClass("current");
}
```

Also, on the site, the image seems to fadeIn and fadeOut twice on the site and I can't figure it out. http://www.cinderblockcomedyfestival.com/new/

Answer (score 1):

```
// inside $(document).ready ...

var speed = 1000;

setTimeout(function playSlide(){
    slideNext();
    setTimeout( playSlide, speed );
}, speed);
```